# ¿Cómo se hace una advertencia de eliminado con Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Es para una aplicación de un control de inasistencia que en ella tiene una  opción de buscar alumno en ella se encuentran dos botones llamados actualizar y eliminar.

Lo que yo quiero, y no se como hacerlo, es que cuando el usuario presione alguno de los botones le aparezca un mensaje de advertencia que fija desea eliminar este estudiante o en el otro casi desea actualizar estos datos.

Comment: Para eso puedes realizar con la función confirm(). Si necesitas ayuda deberías compartir tu código, así se te puede ayudar con mayor facilidad, te dejo el link de un ejemplo sencillo de "w3schools": https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes trabajar con la función **confirm** de javascript.

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <!-- Ejemplo de listado de usuarios -->
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Nombres</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Juan Perez</td>
                <td>
                    <button onclick="actualizar()">Actualizar</button>
                    <!-- Activo el evento click en la acción eliminar -->
                    <button onclick="eliminar()">Eliminar</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function actualizar() {
        // Ingresar código
    }

    function eliminar() {
        var c = confirm("¿Está seguro de eliminar el usuario?");
        if (c == true) {
            alert('Usuario eliminado');
        } else {
            alert('Acción cancelada');
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizar `confirm()` dispara un recuadro que de retornar `true` ejectua la función y si es `false` ejecuta lo contrar (si usaste un else)

Ejemplo funcional:

```js
var haceralgo = () => {
  if (confirm("¿Deseas hacer algo?")) {
    document.write("algo se hizo");
  } else {
    alert("No se hará nada")
  }

}
```

```html
<button onclick="haceralgo()">Hacer algo</button>
```

Comment: Pero es es funcion se usa también. PHP y no se como agragar javascrip allí

Comment: @julieta podrías añadir el código que estás usando para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Para lo que pides es fácil de entender a la ligera

```js
var boton = document.getElementById('id_boton');
boton.onclick = function validar(){
var confirmacion = confirm("Desea ejecutar la función?");
  if (confirmacion){
     alert("Aceptastes");
  }
  else{
     alert("Cancelastes");
  }
};
```

Comment: Pero también se usa PHP y no se